# Bounded derivative of a function is continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I am just confused whether the following statement is true or wrong.

Let $f$ be a continuous function on $[a,b]$, and differentiable on $(a,b)$ such that $f^{'}$ is bounded on $(a,b)$. Does it follow that $f^{'}$ is continuous?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Counterexample:

$$f(x) = \begin{cases}
x^{2}\sin\frac{1}{x} & x\neq0\\
0 & x=0
\end{cases}$$
$$dom(f) = [-1,1]$$
$$f(x)  \mbox{ is continuous}$$
$$f'(x) = \begin{cases}
2x\sin\frac{1}{x}-\cos\frac{1}{x} & x\neq0\\
0 & x=0
\end{cases}$$
$$f'  \mbox{is bounded on }[-1,1]$$
$$f'  \mbox{is NOT continuous}$$